# Facebook login on windows 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to build a phone app on the windows phone, I've decided to use Facebook as a mean of authentication, for users to login. I've been reading through the Facebook Mobile Dev page, but I couldn't see any SDK for a window phone native app.

Am I missing something? Is there another technique to login the user through Facebook?

Comment: I wrote a sample [WP7 login control](https://github.com/offbysome/Facebook-WP7-Login-Button) that you can check out. Also check out the C# Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use OAuth in the web browser to get this to work. I used the [Facebook c# sdk](http://docs.csharpsdk.org/) by following instructions on [Prabir's Blog](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx).

George